# R6010 Error When Using; std::stoi

Tags: c++, string, std

I have been getting the error `R6010 - abort() has been called.` from the `std::stoi()` call and have now find out why, ill start by showing the code at hand;

```
    std::string str;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberofvalues; i++)
    {
        str = cmemblock[i];
        if (cmemblock[i] == '\n' || cmemblock[i] == '\r')
        {
            cout << cmemblock[i] << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            int number = std::stoi(str);
            cout << number;
        }
    }
```

The aim of the program at this stage is to read a .txt file and display the output in int format, the error occurs when the .txt file has more than 1 line of data.

I should also note that `cmemblock` is the text file stored in a CharArrayPtr format.

What I need is some guidance as to how I can represent all lines of data in int format.

Comment: Ahem, I just forgot what `R6010` meant for the moment??

Comment: Apologies, Debug error, R6010 - abort() has been called. Thats the message that pops up.

Comment: What's the exact content of the file? `std::stoi()` might abort for several reasons e.g. non numeric input. You probably have some line endings in your buffer or such. You can try reading the input from a `std::istringstream` initialized with the buffered data and using the `operator>>(std::istream&, int&)` alternatively.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ the text file only contains numbers, which at a later stage will include negative and decimal numbers. I have ran a few tests to check and its definitely having issues with a new line hence I've amended the code as shown in the edit above. But its still having problems after the last character is converted to int.

Comment: For now the content is; "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9". Comma indicating a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `std::stoi()` expects to see a single numeric input in the `std::string` argument passed, e.g.:

```
int x = std::stoi("12345");
```

No extra characters, line endings, multiple lines, etc. are expected. You can use a `std::istringstream` initialized from `str` alternatively:

```
std::string str = &(cmemblock[0]);
std::istringstream iss(str);
int number;
if(!(iss >> number)) {
    // print error ...
}
```

To read more values subsequently (delimited by whitespace or `'\n'`) you can also make a loop:

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
int number;
while(iss >> number) {
    // collect inputs
    numbers.push_back(number);
}

if(!iss.eof()) {
    // input format error occurred ...
}
```

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks. How would I `cout` iss or str? I have tried std::cout to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: @NoobProgrammer `str` should work with `std::cout` as usual: `std::cout << str << std::endl` (note the `std::endl` flushes the stream and makes it at least visible on screen, alternatively use `std::cout.flush();` as an extra statement afterwards). To check the actual string contents of `std::istringstream iss` you can use `iss.str()` method.

Comment: Its working just how I wanted, now that is in int format how would I read a double digit? for example,'15' as 1 and a 5. My aim is basically to represent numbers stored in a .txt file as morse code, I have arrays to represent the morse code but I need to read each number individually, I have an idea to do this in the form of a loop but it needs the integer to be a string, would this be the ideal method do you think?

Comment: @NoobProgrammer You can simply change the input variable type to `double`, but the input representation needs to reflect floating point format to get the decimal fractions, e.g. `"1.5"`. If your values are always two digits wide and the second (or even last in case of more digits given) digit is assumed to be the 10th, or vice versa the 1st digit is always assumed to be the 0-9 whole integer part, you can adjust the values using appropriate division/multiplication operations. You'll need to decide where the decimal point should be placed on your current input, or have it in the input string.

Comment: @NoobProgrammer Please consider accepting my answer, if it actually solved your primary problems asked here. For further problems with your code, consider asking another question. This will help other users/visitors here to track on the right Q&A topics in SO, as it's intended.